# Accessing active Business Unit from Morphx Ax 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, morph-x

I am new to Ms Dynamics Ax. How can we access currently active Business Unit from Morphx. I need to add one textField in Create Sales Order form that will automatically take currently Active Business Unit. Any help will be appreciated ..
Thanx!!

Comment: How do you define "active business unit"? Do you mean the current legal entity or company?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the active Company you are working with and the user ist logged in, the answer is

curext();

If your are looking for the Company the SalesOrder saved in you can also Access the

SalesTable.DataAreaId